# send mail using exchange server

Tags: ip, exchange-server, public

In Exchange server internal mails are working but when i send to external (outside) its not sending.

I have 2 NIC cards nic1  10.20.40.50,gateway : 10.20.40.32 and dns 10.20.40.32.   Nic 2 : external public ip without gateway.A record and mx record is entered for the public ip in DNS. Firewall is not blocking the port.

I know we can use only one gateway. Now when i send internal mails its working. But when i try to send outside its stuck in message queue in exchange server.

Please let me know how to configure this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is hard give exact instructions without knowing which version of Exchange you are running.

Regardless of Exchange version, it sounds like you don't have any connector configured to actually send mail to domains outside your Exchange organisation.

For Exchange 2013 and 2016 you need to follow these instructions to [Create a Send connector to send mail to the internet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/mail-flow/connectors/internet-mail-send-connectors)

Comment: Thank you. I have used smarthost to send mails and its fine.